# Costum scheme doesn`t validate data FASTAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

In the custom scheme, I defined the price field as a number, but passing a string there, the scheme did not validate in any way and did not throw an error. How can this behavior be changed without resorting to Pidantic models?

Code:

```
def magic_data_reader(raw_body: bytes):
    raw_body = dict(eval(raw_body))
    return {
        "size": len(raw_body),
        "content": {
            "name": raw_body['name'],
            "price": raw_body['price'],
            "description": raw_body['description'],
        },
    }


@router.post(
    "/items/",
    openapi_extra={
        "requestBody": {
            "content": {
                "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                        "required": ["name", "price"],
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {"type": "string"},
                            "price": {"type": "number"},
                            "description": {"type": "string"},
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": True,
        },
    },
)
async def create_item(request: Request):
    raw_body = await request.body()
    data = magic_data_reader(raw_body)
    return data
```

Request:

```
{
  "name": "Jack",
  "price": "dddd",
  "description": "Something"
}
```

Response body:

```
{
  "size": 3,
  "content": {
    "name": "Jack",
    "price": "dddd",
    "description": "Something"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need to do this? Half of the point of using FastAPI is the automatic validation using Pydantic.

Comment: @M.O. I agree, but the documentation describes this feature, and I don't understand how I can use it

Answer (score 2):

The `openapi_extra` parameter just adds information to the OpenAPI documentation, it does not generate any validation logic. As described in [the documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/path-operation-advanced-configuration/?h=openapi_extra#custom-openapi-path-operation-schema), this is a feature, e.g. if you want to write your own custom validation logic:

> For example, you could decide to read and validate the request with your own code, without using the automatic features of FastAPI with Pydantic, but you could still want to define the request in the OpenAPI schema.

To get the advantages of automatic validation of FastAPI, you have to use Pydantic models.